# Multiple user tracking using pi_tracker

Tags: ros, pi-tracker, skeleton-tracker, skeleton, skeletal-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,

I am using using ROS Electric, and pi_tracker package for skeletal tracking. In the published /skeleton topic by pi_tracker, there is a field named 'user_id'. Although in the tracking window, the tracker can track more than one person, but in the /skeleton topic message, user_id field is always equal to 1. I am not sure, whether it can't track more than one person, or there is any other parameter that needs to be set to get multiple user tracking data. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59917/multiple-user-tracking-using-pi_tracker/) by [Tariq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4429/tariq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could also look at the source for [openni_tracker.cpp](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/openni_tracker/html/openni__tracker_8cpp_source.html) for some hints on how to define unique `tf` frames for each user.

Also, when I first was getting started with ROS+Kinect, I wrote a package that borrowed heavily from `pi_tracker` and `openni_tracker` to provide exactly what you are looking for.  Actually, I essentially did what @Pi_Robot suggested, and I publish arrays of skeleton messages.  You can find my tracker code [here](https://github.com/jakeware/skeletontracker_nu) and the message definitions [here](https://github.com/jakeware/skeletonmsgs_nu).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-04-04**:
I think that your solution is the quickest, and the safest ! Good luck Tariq.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Tariq.  If you look at the file skeleton_tracker.cpp in the pi_tracker/src directory, you will see a break statement after the first user is detected.  This was to simplify the code when I first wrote the package.  So to get started, you could remove this break statement but you would also have to create a new message type such as SkeletonArray that would allow you to publish the frames for all detected users.

I realize that's not much of an answer, but at least it might get you started.

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2013-04-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1